# Equivalent of DbFunctions.AddSeconds in EF core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there an equivalent of the following code in EF core?  This code is being ported from EF 6.

```
where myEntity.CreateDate <= DbFunctions.AddSeconds(DateTime.Now, -60)
```